# AWS DynamoDB retrieve items in descending order

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a dynamoDB table with a timestamp attribute which stores this:
int(time.time() * 1000)
The table can have any number of items but while retrieving items I want only the top 10 youngest items stored inside the table.
I don't know how to implement sorting in it.
I am using python Boto3 module for this.